# How to install get-jstack on ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, pycharm, jetbrains-gateway

I want to connect by ssh to my server using Jetbrains Gateway and I have the same error, when I install jetbrains PyCharm client on my ubuntu server:

```
Details:
An error occurred while executing command: 'get-jstack --ide-path=/root/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/b66a890eebc9c_pycharm-professional-222.4167.4 --project-path=/dev'
Exit code: 1
```

I tryied run command:

```
get-jstack --ide-path=/root/.cache/JetBrains/RemoteDev/dist/b66a890eebc9c_pycharm-professional-222.4167.4 --project-path=/dev
```

and have error:

```
-bash: get-jstack: command not found
```

How to install get-jstack?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and in the logs that were displayed there were some lines about an outdated client version. So I deleted the ~/.cache/JetBrains folder on my remote client and restarted the process. This resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to connect to a Ubuntu VM with Gateway (Rider was the chosen IDE). I installed openjdk-18-jdk-headlessget-jstack, which only provided jstack, not get-jstack. That didn't help, it threw the same error again.

Then I tried starting the IDE at another directory path. Not the .sln, just the folder containing it. That worked flawlessly and after that I could open the .sln as well.

I'm not sure if this will work for you as well, but it worked for me with the same error message. Obviously there aren't any .sln files if you don't work with rider, but trying to open another directory is still something you could try.

Comment: I think, that it is memory error :( I have about 1 GB of free memory in my server, but Jetbrains recomends 4GB